# How to set member variables of class inside class without setter?

Tags: c++, class, variables

I would like to set the values of member variables of a class inside class without using setters.

My code:

```
class MyWindowSettings {

public:

    const ofGLFWWindowSettings& get(){
        return settings;
    }
    int numSamples;
    bool resizable;

private:
    ofGLFWWindowSettings settings;
};
```

`ofGLFWWindowSettings` also has public member variables that are

```
int numSamples;
bool resizable;
```

And I would like to be able to set the values of these variables without using setters.

I would like to be able to.. for instance,

```
MyWindowSettings settings;
settings.numSamples = 8;
settings.resizable = true;
```

Then the internal `ofGLFWWindowSettings`'s `numSamples` and `resizable` should be set to these values immediately.

Is there any possible solution to achieve this without using setters or inheriting `ofGLFWWindowSettings`?

Comment: @P0W How is this question a duplicate to the one you brought? I don't get it.

Comment: If you need to keep the types (i.e. `int` and `bool`) then it is not possible. If not, it could be possible to use a simple reference or wrap the type into another that forwards the assignments, but you really shouldn't go that way. Instead, a simpler, clearer way is to either use setters or let the user call a function to apply the changes (e.g. `apply()`) if you need to set them all at once.

Comment: Note that there's little difference to a *consumer* of a class between an `int` public member and an `int &` public member.

Comment: @ZackLee why can't you use member initialization list for `ofGLFWWindowSettings` ? I don't get it as well

Comment: @P0W the question is about *using* the members of `ofGLFWWindowSettings` not *initialising* them

Comment: @Caleth Thanks for saying it!

Comment: @Caleth I still don't get it _"And I would like to be able to set the values of these variables without using setters."_ ? Could you please re-edit it ?

Comment: @P0W Re-edit how?

Comment: @ZackLee never mind, you're question is re-opened. I think some of us know what actually you're asking or trying to achieve. You'll soon get an answer.

Comment: @P0W: Why he can or can't use initialization is not the point of this question. For instance, an answer to this question would be using an additional non const version of his getter. This is not covered in the question you linked.

Comment: @GuntherPiez I'm not sure where OP is asking for _getting_ the values, all I see is setters, setting, etc.

Comment: No. (This space intentionally left blank).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple of options, with varying amounts of similarity to the syntax you prefer.

Option 1 - member references

```
class MyWindowSettings {

public:
    MyWindowSettings()
      : numSamples(settings.numSamples),
        resizable(settings.resizable)
    {}

    ~MyWindowSettings() = default;

    MyWindowSettings(const MyWindowSettings & other)
      : settings(other.settings),
        numSamples(settings.numSamples),
        resizable(settings.resizable)
    {}

    MyWindowSettings& operator=(const MyWindowSettings & other)
    {
        settings = other.settings;
        return *this;
    }

    MyWindowSettings(MyWindowSettings && other)
      : settings(std::move(other.settings)),
        numSamples(settings.numSamples),
        resizable(settings.resizable)
    {}

    MyWindowSettings& operator=(MyWindowSettings && other)
    {
        settings = std::move(other.settings);
        return *this;
    }

    const ofGLFWWindowSettings& get(){
        return settings;
    }
    int & numSamples;
    bool & resizable;

private:
    ofGLFWWindowSettings settings;
};
```

Pro:

- Exactly the syntax that you want.

Con:

- Very verbose definition. Easy to miss a mistake in there somewhere.

Option 2 - public `ofGLFWWindowSettings`

```
class MyWindowSettings {   
public:
    ofGLFWWindowSettings settings;
};
```

Pro:

- Very concise
- You don't need the getter for `ofGLFWWindowSettings` too

Con:

- Not quite the same syntax

I personally prefer this, assuming there are other members of `MyWindowSettings` not shown.

```
MyWindowSettings settings;
settings.settings.numSamples = 8;
settings.settings.resizable = true;
```

Option 3 - No `MyWindowSettings`

Just use `ofGLFWWindowSettings` directly instead

Option 3.a - alias definition

```
 using MyWindowSettings = ofGLFWWindowSettings;
```

Comment: "Yes this is possible" is not a very good answer if after following the advice in industrial settings you get fired with prejudice.

Comment: @n.m. which would you fire me for? And would this be before or after giving me the coding style document that you measure this by?

Comment: For the first one. This is gross abuse of the language for sake of notation. You don't need this notation. Nobody needs any specific notation.

Comment: @n.m. I agree that nobody needs this notation, but the question specifically asked for this notation, so it makes sense for any solution to provide it...

Comment: If somebody asks you how to shoot himself in the foot, will you give detailed recommendations? I won't. If he is so inclined, let him do that without my help.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the code of the class `ofGLFWWindowSettings` a possibility is to define its members `itn numSamples` and `bool resizable` as references, to be inizialied in the constructor. Then the constructor of `MyWindowSettings` passes its members `int numSamples`, `bool resizable` (after initialization) to the constructor of `ofGLFWWindowSettings`.

See the following example:

```
struct ofGLFWWindowSettings {
    int& numSamples;
    bool& resizable;

    ofGLFWWindowSettings(int& _numSamples, bool& _resizable) :
                numSamples(_numSamples), resizable(_resizable) { }
};

class MyWindowSettings {

public:

    const ofGLFWWindowSettings& get(){
        return settings;
    }
    int numSamples;
    bool resizable;



  MyWindowSettings(int _numSamples, bool _resizable) :
          numSamples(_numSamples), resizable(_resizable),
          settings(numSamples, resizable) { }


private:
    ofGLFWWindowSettings settings;
};
```

Being `ofGLFWWindowSettings::numSamples` and `ofGLFWWindowSettings::resizable` merely references, they are always up to date.

If you instead need a more complex behavior when writing `settings.numSamples = 8`, such as modifying the object `ofGLFWWindowSettings settings` or call some other member function, then you could overload the `operator=`. That is, instead of declaring `MyWindowSettings::numSamples` as a simple int, you could declare it as a user-defined class, which redefines its `operator=` to take a int and, at the same time, to do some other work, as needed. But at this point, I guess that a "setter" routine would be an easier choice.

Answer (score 1):

YES - if you use Visual Studio compiler.

You can set numSamples and resizable using [declspec(property)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd.aspx), your code would look like this:

```
class MyWindowSettings
{
public:
__declspec( property( put=SetSamples ) ) int numSamples;
__declspec( property( put=SetResizable ) ) bool resizable;

private:
    void SetSamples(int s)
    {
        numSamples = s;
        UpdateOfgl();
    }
    void SetResizable(bool b)
    {
        resizable = b;
        UpdateOfgl();
    }

    void UpdateOfgl()
    {
        //update ofgl settings internal state
    }
}
```